# Is there a short way to modify DateTime to "today" but keep the previous stored time?

Tags: php, datetime

There's a `DateTime`-object. I want to set it to **today** and keep the time.

For example:

- it's set to *2012-10-12 10:30:00*
- it should become *2012-11-22 10:30:00*

This won't work of course:

```
// this obviously changes it to 2012-11-22 00:00:00
$date->modify('today'));
```

This will work, but seems like a little much effort:

```
$clone = clone $date();
$date->modify('today')->setTime($clone->format('H'), $clone->format('i'));
```

Is there a shorter/more efficient way?

Comment: Keep in mind that, depending on your time zone, some times will be legal on one day and not on another. For example, if you're in a US time zone that has daylight savings, on the day that daylight savings time moves forward, there is no 2:01am, the clock jumps directly to 3:00am. Thoroughly test how your app works in this situation to make sure you don't have problems once a year that magically go away. Or set your timezone to UTC and ignore all these types of problems. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not much better:

```
$newDate = new DateTime('today '.$date->format('H:i'));
```

Comment: +1 `$date->modify( 'today ' . $date->format( 'H:i' ) );` will work too then, of course.